# Regex from substring to first occurrence of another substring

Tags: regex, perl

I need to eliminate the textClipping files from a list. Unfortuately some files have been terribly named and contain a carriage return. I need the perl regex for that would match each path from `/Volumes/` to `.textClipping` including newline.

`/Volumes/.*\.textClipping` captures the first two `.textClipping` files, but not the third, with the newline. Alternatively I was able capture everything from first `/Volumes/` to last `.textClipping`, but that's not helpful either.

Any ideas? Thanks a bunch.

```
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.textClipping
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.textClipping
/Volumes/folder/folder/fi  

le.textClipping
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell from your question where in the filenames the newline characters could be, so I'm assuming they could be anywhere. This makes matching more challenging.

The simplest solution might be to remove all newlines from the input before removing the unwanted filenames.

I made this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                            
$filename = "filelist.txt";                                                                                                                                
open(FILE, $filename) or die "Cant open $filename\n";                                                                                                      

# Undefine the record separator, so that the entire file will be read into a single string
# instead of an array with records separated by newlines
local $/ = undef;                                                                                                                                          
$lines = <FILE>;                                                                                                                                           
close(FILE);                                                                                                                                               
print "Before\n------\n";                                                                                                                                  
print $lines;                                                                                                                                              

# Remove all newlines                                                       
$lines =~ s/\n+//g;                                                                                                                                        
# Remove all "textClipping" files
$lines =~ s/\/Volumes\/[^ ]*.textClipping//g;                                                                                                              
# Turn multiple consecutive spaces into single spaces
$lines =~ s/ +/ /g;                                                                                                                                        

print "After\n-----\n";                                                                                                                                    
print "$lines\n";
```

and fed it your example as filelist.txt:

```
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc /Volumes/folder/folder/file.textClipping /Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc /Volumes/folder/folder/file.textClipping /Volumes/folder/folder/fi
le.textClipping /Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc
```

which gave this output:

```
Before
------
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc /Volumes/folder/folder/file.textClipping /Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc /Volumes/folder/folder/file.textClipping /Volumes/folder/folder/fi
le.textClipping /Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc
After
-----
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc /Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc /Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc
```

Finally, I think you should be very cautious using the pattern you suggest in your question:

```
/Volumes/.*.textClipping
```

since . will capture any character except a newline, but including a space. I ran that pattern on this input as suggested by your question:

```
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc /Volumes/folder/folder/file.textClipping /Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc /Volumes/folder/folder/file.textClipping /Volumes/folder/folder/fi
le.textClipping /Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc
```

and got this output, which I don't think is what you want:

```
/Volumes/folder/folder/fi
le.textClipping /Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc
```

**Edit**: you've recently posted an Answer to your own question where you fall into this trap again, but I don't have enough Reputation to post a comment on it. Instead of `/Volumes/.*\n*.textClipping/g` (which will match spaces, and thus potentially get rid of more than one filename at a time) I strongly recommend that you consider `/Volumes/[^ ]*\n*.textClipping/g`; the `[^ ]*` will match everything *except* spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
perl  -0777 -ae '@files = m~(/Volumes/(?:[^/\r\n]+/)+?[^/]+?\.textClipping\R)~g;print scalar(@files)," files found:\n",@files' file.txt
```

Where:

- `-0777` read the file in "slurp" mode
- `-a` autosplit mode

**Regex:**

```
 ~                      : regex delimiter
(                       : start group 1
    /Volumes/           : literally 
    (?:                 : start non capture group
        [^/\r\n]+       : 1 or more any character that is not a slash or line break
        /               : slash
    )+?                 : group repeated 1 or more times, not greedy (ie. the path)
    [^/]+?              : not a slash, 1 or more times, not greedy (ie. the filename)
    \.textClipping      : a dot with the extension
    \R                  : any kind of linebreak
)                       : end group 1
~g                      : regex delimiter, global flag
```

**Output:**

```
3 files found:
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.textClipping
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.textClipping
/Volumes/folder/folder/fi

le.textClipping
```

If you want to keep all files that don't end with `.textClipping`

```
perl  -0777 -i.orig -ape 's~(/Volumes/(?:[^/\r\n]+/)+?[^/]+?\.textClipping\R)~~g' file.txt
```

The input file is modified in-place (option `-i`), original file is backuped with extension `.orig`

```
cat file.txt
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc
/Volumes/folder/folder/file.doc
```

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate the responses. Thank you for your time. I apologize if things weren't clear in my question. The answer turned out to be simpler than I initially thought.

To note, the carriage return or new line in the filename is as follows: "file(CR)name.textClipping". Textclipping files just give the text contained withing as the name of file itself, which in my case is a few carriage returns. Pain in the ass!

None the less, this works:
**/Volumes/.*\n*.textClipping/g**

This matches occurrences strings starting with "/Volumes/", ending with ".textClipping" with everything in between.

Thanks again for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure this is working like you want? Apply on given sample file, it gives for the second match 2 files (line 3 concatenate with line 4)